# "Reopen the Java Control Panel" doesn't do anything

Tags: java

From System Preferences, I open the Java icon and it shows:
[image]

And that's all. The "*Reopen the Java Control Panel*" button doesn't do anything. There isn't any separate window anywhere.

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65).

Comment: It should only show the reopen button if you've already opened it then closed it. I'd at least try a reboot to test, & check for Java Control Panel in Activity Monitor.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Java in Activity Monitor. I'll try a reboot.

Comment: If that doesn't work go to java.com and download an installer and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same thing. And when I try to reinstall it, the Java installer just bounces a few times and never opens a window. Never starts, unable to reinstall it.

I created another profile/account and used it after switching - and the apps that had been failing to start - never use any CPU - would work like they were supposed to.

By now it's pretty obvious something is not right in my home directory, but it's not being intuitive.

Comment: Just to elaborate, quite a number of programs stopped opening since High Sierra - but work fine on the other profile.